# Determining whether MVC3 server validation is successful

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

When returning from an AJAX query, is there a way to determine whether the server side validation added any errors?

I have tried

```
if ($('#MyForm').valid() == true)
...
```

in an `OnSuccess` function, but it seems to always be true, regardless of whether the server side validation failed or not. The refreshed HTML if generates does put in the error as expected, so I know the validation is working correctly.

I suspect the `valid()` method is just re-running the client-side validation.

Comment: Why don't you throw an exception on the server side when the validation fails? This way you could easly catch it in the OnError client event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the technique in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started/custom-validation). Validation is done server side using Data annotations. Using a custom filter, validation errors are sent to the client and on the client side, you call `revalidate()` from the unbotrusive js

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.revalidate(form, validationResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run an ajax call to the server, you can simply compose the Json return.

Usually I wrap my responses in a class containing a property that tell me if all is ok,
one that contain the data and one with the eventual error message.

```
public class MyJsonReposnse
{
   public bool Valid {get;set;}
   public string Error {get;set;}
   public IList<MyClass> Data {get;set;}
}
```

Then from your controller you return the json and from your `onSuccess` of the jQuery call, you check the value of `Valid` and act accordingly